# User Interface Controls for Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I see many user interface control libraries for .NET, but where can I get similar stuff for win32 using simply C/C++?

Things like prettier buttons, dials, listviews, graphs, etc.

Seems every Win32 programmers' right of passage is to end up writing his own collection.  :/

---

No MFC controls please.  I only do pure C/C++.  And with that said, I also don't feel like adding a multi-megabyte framework to my application just so that I can have a prettier button.

---

I apologize for leaving out one tiny detail, and that is that my development is for Windows Mobile.

So manifest files are out.

I just notice how many developer companies have gone crazy with making pretty looking .NET components and wondered where the equivalent C/C++ Win32 components have gone?

I read about how many people ended up writing their own gradient button class, etc.  So you would think that there would be some commercial classes for this stuff.  It's just weird.

I'll take a closer look at QT and investigate its GUI support for such things.  This is the challenge when you're the one man in your own uISV.  No other developers to help you "get things done".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [Trolltech's Qt framework](http://trolltech.com/products/qt/) in the past and had great success with it:
In addition, it's also cross-platform, so in theory you can target Win, Mac, & Linux (provided you don't do anything platform-specific in the rest of your code, of course ;) )

Edit: I notice that you're targeting Windows Mobile; that definitely adds to Qt's strength, as its cross-platform support extends to [WinCE and Embedded Linux](http://trolltech.com/products/qt/features/platforms/index) as well.

Comment: I looked at QT myself some months back, and it works out quite expensive if you want to use it for commercial applications.  A bit of a shame as it looks great from a cross platform perspective.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it hasn't been well managed these past few years. Shame indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I you don't mind using the MFC libraries you should try the [Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

[Stingray](http://www.roguewave.com/products/stingray.php)

[CodeJock](http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/?2yn6s14z=zsp) - Toolkit Pro for MFC/ C++

Comment: I use Stingray on the desktop and an older version on Windows CE and mobile.  Great if you're into MFC, not so good if you want cross platform support, don't like large frameworks, and don't like MFC.  RogueWave don't support mobile, I had to modify the old CE version to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

[The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) has lots of UI controls for C/C++

Most of them are focussed on MFC or WTL but there are some that are pure [Win32](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/).

As an aside if you're not using a framework, you really should consider WTL over pure Win32.  It's low overhead and about a million times more productive.

Answer (score 1):

For prettier buttons, etc., if you aren't already doing it, [embed an application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175(VS.85).aspx) so that your program is linked to version 6 of the common controls library.  Doing so will get you the Windows XP- or Vista-styled versions of the standard Windows controls.

If you want types of controls beyond what Windows offers natively, you'll likely have to either write it yourself or be more specific about what kind of control you are looking for.

Comment: I just did this to pretty up a Visual C++ 6 application.  Worked fine with the manifest in the same directory.  To get it compiled in via the resource.rc file I had to add:
1 24 "YourApplication.exe.manifest"
Because CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID == 1 and RT_MANIFEST == 24

Answer (score 0):

The MFC feature pack is derived from [BCGSoft components](http://www.bcgsoft.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Using winAPI's you can do almost anything you want and really fast too. It takes some time to figure it out but it works. Go to MSDN, lookup MessageBox(), check out DialogBox() and go from there.

I personally do not care for MFC by the way. If you want to use an MFC like approach I'd recommend  Borland's C++ Builder. Pretty old but still very usefull I think.